# autogenerate number from database in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, auto-generate

I used the solution below, but whenever I delete a particular row it will duplicate the number.

Code:

```
void AutoGenerateId()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConString);
    string Query = "select COUNT(*) from StudentDetails";
    SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand(Query, cn);
    try
    {
        cn.Open();
        int count = Convert.ToInt16(cd.ExecuteScalar()) + 1;
        txtStudentId.Text = count.ToString();
        txtStudentId.Enabled = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblErrorMsg.Text = ex.ToString();
    }
    finally
    {
        cn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't the slightest clue what you're asking...

Comment: I _think_ I get what you're asking, kinda. Use `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(StudentDetails) + 1` rather than count, if you're trying to get the (potential) next increment value. I say potential because it could change before you commit. You'll also need an Identity column, otherwise use MAX(Id) if not IDENTITY (it should be).

Comment: or just use Id INT IDENTITY(1,1)

Comment: Use a sequencer

Comment: You don't have a primary key?

Comment: i just need auto increment value in text box
how should i do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [sequencer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) to generate ids and get the next one.

Example:

```
string query = "SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR Student.Sequence;"
```

This will return a unique number, even if you remove a row.

Comment: It gives error that invalid object name 'Std_Info.Id'